# Duality behavior of light and effect of system scale on its behavior

Tags: quantum-field-theory, optics, electromagnetic-radiation

Does an electromagnetic wave that makes by antenna behaves purely as wave for all the times? or it can change its behavior as photon?
and does the scale of system effect on behaving as EM wave or photon? or precisely does electromagnetic interaction at quantum  scale exchanges photon and at the large scale propagates EM wave?

Comment: Photons make up the electromagnetic wave, how can the wave become its part?

Comment: Well since a photon *is* an electromagnetic wave, I'd say it's certainly possible that an electromagnetic wave suddenly becomes itself. In fact, I think EM waves are becoming photons and vice versa every instant in time simply by virtue of them being the same thing.

Comment: imagine a microwave that use for communication, before detection by the antenna, suddenly behaves as a photon, so how antenna encode the wave information?

Answer (score 3):

In classical field theory,  electromagnetic wave is just a wave,  and nothing more,  this what Maxwell equations tells us.

But during 20'th century,  more and more experiments were suggesting that electromagnetic wave behaves like particles, for example it was able to hit electrons in atoms and force them to pop up out of the metal surface, and apparently the usual wave picture for electromagnetic wave is not enough.

And after Plank suggested that energy may be quantized, Einstein suggested this quanta is responsible for photoeffect, and each quanta is photon, and this is particle wave duality,  and quantum field theory describes it.

Thus according to modern understandings,  there are no differences between photon and electromagnetic wave, so turning one into another has no sense, however, it can seem that it behaves some times like a pure wave,  and some time as a pure particle,  depending on the experiment setup.

Comment: i know there no differences between photon and electromagnetic wave, but i can't understand that how a EM wave that makes by antenna can behave as photon?

Answer (score 2):

One can see that the electromagnetic wave is a flow of particles from the `photo-electric` effect.  This means that electrons are not simply washed off by an accumulation of energy from photons, like a wave, but require that individual parts of the wave (photons), have sufficient energy to hit individual electrons out of an atom.

On the other hand, one can render a space so dark that there is only one photon in the box at once.  Even so, there is a defraction of the photon through the double-slit, as if it were a wave.

Answer (score 1):

Electromagnetic wave is the stream of photons.